# How to obtain more than 5 results from google.maps.places.Autocomplete?

Tags: android, google-maps, autocomplete

In my application, I am displaying google.maps.places.Autocomplete view integrated in an html page in a webview. While typing on it, I am getting only 5 dropdown results. How can I increase the search results? Anyone please help..

Comment: simple answer is you can not do that

Comment: i have spent almost 3-4 days and i got same answer that it is not possible

Answer (score 7):

From the documentation:

> A JSON response contains two root elements:
>
> "status" contains metadata on the request. See Status Codes below.
>
> "predictions" contains an array of places, with information about the
> place. **The Places API returns up to 5 results.**

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_responses